# Exporting magick gif that contains multiple gganimate animations as mp4

Tags: r, gganimate

I am trying to export a gif containing multiple gganimate animations that was created using magick as a mp4.

The code here: https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/wiki/Animation-Composition shows an example of putting gganimate animations side by side using magick but the result is a gif. For ease, I have copy and pasted below

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(magick)
library(gganimate)


A<-rnorm(100,50,10)
B<-rnorm(100,50,10)
DV <- c(A,B)
IV <- rep(c("A","B"),each=100)
sims <- rep(rep(1:10,each=10),2)
df<-data.frame(sims,IV,DV)

means_df <- df %>%
  group_by(sims,IV) %>%
  summarize(means=mean(DV),
            sem = sd(DV)/sqrt(length(DV)))

stats_df <- df %>%
  group_by(sims) %>%
  summarize(ts = t.test(DV~IV,var.equal=TRUE)$statistic)

a <- ggplot(means_df, aes(x = IV,y = means, fill = IV)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_point(aes(x = IV, y = DV), data = df, alpha = .25) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = means - sem, ymax = means + sem), width = .2) +
  theme_classic() +
  transition_states(
    states = sims,
    transition_length = 2,
    state_length = 1
  ) + 
  enter_fade() + 
  exit_shrink() +
  ease_aes('sine-in-out')

a_gif <- animate(a, width = 240, height = 240)

b <- ggplot(stats_df, aes(x = ts))+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = ts, frame = sims))+
  geom_line(aes(x=x,y=y),
            data = data.frame(x = seq(-5,5, .1),
                              y = dt(seq(-5,5, .1), df = 18))) +
  theme_classic() +
  ylab("density") +
  xlab("t value") +
  transition_states(
    states = sims,
    transition_length = 2,
    state_length = 1
  ) +
  enter_fade() + 
  exit_shrink() +
  ease_aes('sine-in-out')

b_gif <- animate(b, width = 240, height = 240)

a_mgif <- image_read(a_gif)
b_mgif <- image_read(b_gif)

new_gif <- image_append(c(a_mgif[1], b_mgif[1]))
for(i in 2:100){
  combined <- image_append(c(a_mgif[i], b_mgif[i]))
  new_gif <- c(new_gif, combined)
}

new_gif
```

I want this as a mp4 for presentations etc but I cant get it to export as a mp4.

```
#convert to mp4
new_mp4 <- image_convert(new_gif, "mp4")
```

I have tried the below to export as a mp4 but I receive the error message:
Error in magick_image_write(image, format, quality, depth, density, comment) : rsession.exe: UnableToOpenFile `C:/Users/Laptop/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp0OreMf/magick-7112S8TmAcW23ct90.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/FileToBlob/987

```
#write the mp4
new_mp4%>%image_write("anim.mp4",format="mp4" )
```

Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work". Do you get an error? Nothing is produced? Have you tried running the imagemagick commands from the console to make sure the commands work for your setup?

Comment: The first line to convert to mp4 works, but the line to write the mp4 returns the error:  Error in magick_image_write(image, format, quality, depth, density, comment) : 
  rsession.exe: UnableToOpenFile `C:/Users/Laptop/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp0OreMf/magick-7112S8TmAcW23ct90.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/FileToBlob/987

Comment: Please include those errors in your original question. Is the file there? If yes, there may be permission issues.

Comment: No, the file isn't there.